What is the correct way to include a VERY large table into the code? in С++
There are very large hashtables in my code, they are used for calculation. Right now the 2 tables are a 5,000,000 array of type float. There will probably be more tables, of larger size.
When I include them in the code, Clion starts to slow down a lot, syntax highlighting stops working. But they are stored in a separate file and are included like this #include "table1.h".
At the moment, I'm like this:
namespace ns{

    class Calc{ 
    public:
        Calc() {}
        static float table1[5000000];
        static float table2[5000000];
    private:
    };
}

I know it's not a good idea to make them public, but for now I've done it this way for convenience, then I'll move them to privat.
and the tables themselves are declared separately in files table1.h and table2.h, like this:
#include "Calc.h"
float ns::Calc::table1[5000000] = {.../*here initialization*/...};

I have a few questions:

How to include them into the code correctly so that Clion does not analyze them and these files are not analyzed in any way until compilation.Maybe they should be taken out of the class and made global variables? They are static anyway.

If some of these tables will be const, how to do the same with const array.


IMPORTANT. Giving advice, take into account that I am a beginner, and please try to make the information as accessible as possible. But I will be very grateful for any help and will understand any answer.I will be interested in ANY information on working with large amounts of data.

"very large hashtables" - Are the hashes used as indices in these arrays? How do you detect hash collisions? What is the underlying objective with the code?

use std::embed. In C there's #embed

@TedLyngmo Yes, each table key is unique and is at the same time a position in the table. This table is created, programmatically using a function, and then this one is included in the code. I do not detect collisions, because there are none. Perhaps I don't understand yet what ideal hashing is, but I think this is an ideal hash table.

If there are no collisions, it's bijective (which means you can recreate the exact values you used as input to the "hash" function by looking at the value). Well, if you run a program to create the tables, then compile the tables into a static library and just link to that.

@TedLyngmo I'm still a newbie I apologize if this is a stupid question. So I need to create a static library with only 1 file - this table? And the table will be copied into RAM during execution to speed up calculations?

"files table1.h" Should it be in a .c instead?

@TedLyngmo Thanks a lot, I did as you said, everything works.
Can you please tell me, is this the only optimal way or are there others? How about embed, I'm still figuring it out, will it work in this case?

@AlexanderGromov No problem! You could compile many .cpp files into the library if you wish to have table1.cpp, table2.cpp etc. Keeping them separate is probably a good idea since you can then compile all tableX.cpp files at the same time and then make a library of the object files. There are probably other ways of doing it. I haven't used #embed myself so I don't know how well it works.

Do you really need all that memory at once?  Can you perform the calculations in pieces?  Long time ago, programmers would only read in blocks of data, process the data, then read in more data.  This allows the programmer to use small blocks of actual memory.  In modern times, the data will be in a virtual memory, which is usually paged out to a hard drive; which doesn't really gain any performance benefits.

@ThomasMatthews I don't know what you mean yet. You mean mapping? If it is, I don't know what it is yet, but it seems interesting.  I am a beginner, please tell me more about it or give links to understand what you mean.

Lets say that the operating system only has 1k for your program to use.    If you declare a 10k an array, the OS will allocate 9k (or 10k) on the hard drive to contain your array.  If you need to access a slot in the 2k range, the OS will read the 2k portion from the drive and overwrite the data in memory.  Research "virtual memory".

The ancient method is to use blocks of data.  For example, if your data is 10k and your buffer is 1k, you would read in 1k  of data, process it, then read in the next 1k and process.  Repeat until all data has been processed.  This is a good technique for the cases where you read in data, process it, then discard it.

@ThomasMatthews Portions are definitely not an option. There will be a loss in speed. Does mapping have something in common with virtual memory in OS or is it just an example? I've read about mapping and it might be a solution.

I don't understand how my suggestions will be a loss of speed.  If your OS does not have enough memory, dedicated to program, it will write the data to the hard drive.  So, you will be reading in data and having the OS write it back to the "virtual memory" area.  Have you profiled these techniques and compared them?

@ThomasMatthews After all, it takes time to read data and then write it. Wouldn't that result in a loss of speed? I need all the data at the same time, because I don't know which ones I might need.

Don't put them in header files at all, just the declaration of the arrays. Keep the actual contents in a regular object file (.cpp) that gets compiled once. That should make your IDE (and especially your compiler) much happier.
So instead of having the definitions in a header file that you presumably include all over the place, instead have files like table1.cpp with the exact same contents that doesn't get included anywhere:
#include "Calc.h"
float ns::Calc::table1[5000000] = {.../*here initialization*/...};


So I just need to rename the file to table1.cpp to solve the problem?
And change the inclusion to "#include "table1.cpp" ? Or should I not do that?

You need a header file to declare that the table exists (e.g. extern) and its symbolic name. The actual definition of the table, with contents, goes in a .cpp file that is linked in to the rest of the code.

OP probably already has the equivalent of this — otherwise, there would be linker errors about multiple definitions. Unless OP specifically allowed multiple definitions (which would be a bad idea).

@AlexanderGromov no, you don't #include it anywhere. You just add the .cpp to the list of source files so it gets compiled alongside all the other source files.

@AlexanderGromov Avoid including cpp files. It almost always makes things worse, and when it doesn't it results in confusion and confused people insert bugs. In the cases where it looks like you need to do it, at least use a different name, ie not c, cpp, or any name used for files that will be compiled into translation units.

Suppose you compile your project with the following commands:
g++ -c calc.cpp
g++ -c table1.cpp
g++ calc.o table1.o -o program

If you have control on your build process, you can use objcopy to insert data directly into the object file table1.o before the linker uses it.
g++ -c calc.cpp
g++ -c table1.cpp
objcopy table1.o --update-section .rodata=table1.bin table1_updated.o
g++ calc.o table1_updated.o -o program

Here the data are in the file table1.bin in binary format — you must create it using fwrite on an array of float values. Or in python, using something like struct.pack('f', value).
And (important!) to prevent data corruption, the only thing in the file table1.cpp should be a dummy definition of your array, with the same name but dummy data:
const float ns::Calc::table1[] = {0};

Note const here — that's why I used .rodata in the command line. If you want changeable data, use .data instead (but there is no reason to).

How does it work?
Compiler creates a .rodata section in the object file; this section contains all the read-only variables the source file defines. Having only one variable ensures that the .rodata section corresponds exactly to that variable.
When objcopy replaces the data in the .rodata section, it looks as if your array now contains the new data. Note: the object file contains no size of the array. If your data file is smaller or larger than required, your array will be padded with garbage values or truncated.
This trick uses equivalence between float[50000] and float[1] — you can declare one and define the other, and it will work. This is not guaranteed, but existing compilers work this way.

Also very not necessary and very frail. Proper C++ code will always write data to the correct sections.

There are the defines for the purpose.
More about the subject
#include "Calc.h"
float ns::Calc::table1[5000000] = {
#ifndef __JETBRAINS_IDE__
.../*here initialization*/...
#endif //__JETBRAINS_IDE__
};

